# SpriteKit exhibiting large CPU overhead

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm writing my first SpriteKit app in Swift.  In Xcode I chose to creat a new SpriteKit project, and it loads a demo project, where every time you touch the screen a spinning spaceship appears.

The first thing I noticed was the CPU percentage was pretty high.  So I started trimming things from the project, until I had literally deleted everything from the GameViewController's `viewDidLoad`.  This is all that remains:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

That's all : not even a scene.  Even so, with nothing but a gray screen visible, I read CPU usage at 35%!  This can't be right. When I run non-game apps on this computer (a Mac Mini), the usage rarely goes higher than 2%.

Does this seem normal?

Comment: If you are testing on the simulator (which I'm assuming you are because you mentioned the Mac Mini) then it is completely useless. You need to test on an actual device.

Comment: I was running a simulator.  Just ran it on my iPhone 6 and registered 7%. Much lower, but still seems high for a literally just a gray screen.  But maybe that's a normal amount of overhead for a game engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Epic Byte's comment was correct. CPU usage on a simulator can differ greatly from a real device.